# PHP SimpleXMLElement parsing xml from url

Tags: php, xml, url, simplexml

I'm trying to parse a XML file from a URL using SimpleXMLElement.
When i try:

```
$url = 'http://dl.dropbox.com/u/27440550/test.xml';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, 0, true, "", false);
```

Everything works fine, i can access the XML document and parse it. Notice the url is a link to my dropbox public folder where i stored the xml file.

When i try to get the file directly from the url:

```
$url = 'https://multidoc.eia-fr.ch/record/1220/export/xd';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, 0, true, "", false);
```

I get weird errors:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found in C:\wamp\www\metamin\getxml.php on line 5

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: https://multidoc.eia-fr.ch/record/1220/export/xd in C:\wamp\www\metamin\getxml.php on line 5

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [<a href='simplexmlelement.--construct'>simplexmlelement.--construct</a>]: ^ in C:\wamp\www\metamin\getxml.php on line 5

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in C:\wamp\www\metamin\getxml.php on line 5

Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in C:\wamp\www\metamin\getxml.php on line 5
```

So I think it's not recognizing it as a XML file but why? Am I not doing the same thing?

Comment: Could be because of the SSL encryption - note the https in the URL, although I am not sure.

Comment: That's it! just enable the  php_openssl extension in wamp server and it's good. 

Thanks alot Jeff!!

Comment: You're welcome - you should add that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could be because of the SSL encryption - note the https in the URL,
>   although I am not sure.

Thanks to **Jeff**